# How to remove special characters and codes (using jquery) from sharepoint rendered html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, branding

I am Working on a branding of share-point application. In some cases, rendered html contains codes like '​'. In my slider, these are generated 8 times and in modal and content pages, their count is different. These codes are generating undesired white space. How can I remove these using jQuery? I tried to play with this like

```
$(".wrapper").filter(function(){
  return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === "&#8203;";
}).remove();
```

But its not working.

Comment: code like "&#8203;"

Comment: <div class=""><h4 class="dayHeading">Event2 </h4><p class="dayText"></p><div class="ExternalClass6DFC2F1A5BDA478BBC53246ED1FC5D7B"><p>&#8203;<span style="color:#000000;font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;text-align:justify;background-color:#ffffff;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tempor pariatur nam elementum, ullam elementum, felis lectus penatibus donec cras, vehicula tincidunt amet aliquet posuere, ac suspendisse dignissim feugiat. Odio mauris</span><img src="/Style%20Library/assets/images/post-image1.png" alt="" ]><br><br></p></div>&#8203;<br><p></p></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code which is a bit DOM-intensive but it does work.

```
$('#s4-bodyContainer').html($('#s4-bodyContainer').html().replace(/\u200B/g,''));
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: You can also check this below link for same issue.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236675/how-to-remove-special-characters-and-codes-using-jquery-from-sharepoint-render